# Comprehensive list of Tikz-timing options

Tags: latex, tikz, timing-diagram

Anyone here a guru in Tikz-timing?

I am looking for a way to label a timing diagram with annotations, but the vertical scale is too compressed.  I couldn't find a comprehensive list of options for the \timing command (or if I did, it was a meager list).

My initial guesses at what they might be failed (e.g. height=), but eventually I stumbled onto an example from the document that confirmed that yscale= should work, and so it does.

Here's a code snippet to get you started:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \timing [yscale=2.0] at (0,0)  {3H N (d7) 3L 3H N (d6) 3L 3H N (d5) 3L 3H N (d4) 3L 3H N (d3)3 L 3H N (d2) 3L 3H N (d1) 3L 3H N (d0) 3L 3H N (ack) 3L};
    \path (d7) node [below left] {D7};
    \path (d6) node [below left] {D6};
    \path (d5) node [below left] {D5};
    \path (d4) node [below left] {D4};
    \path (d3) node [below left] {D3};
    \path (d2) node [below left] {D2};
    \path (d1) node [below left] {D1};
    \path (d0) node [below left] {D0};
    \path (ack) node [below left] {ACK};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of tikz-timing. Stupid question, but did you checked the package manual?
I don't think that you will find any better list of options anywhere.
Check [CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf) or [TeXDoc](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-timing/0).

If you use a recent version of tikz-timing (v0.7) you can use the 'wscale' to scale the width.
Also by adjusting the 'timing/inline node' style to 'rectangle,below left' you can add the node text directly in the timing string by changing the nodes from 'N(d7)' to 'N{d7}' etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \timing [yscale=2.0,timing/wscale=3.0,timing/inline node/.style={rectangle,below left,font=\sffamily}] at (0,0)
  {H N {D7} L H N {D6} L H N {D5} L H N {D4} L H N {D3} L H N {D2} L H N {D1} L H N {D0} L H N[xscale=.8]{ACK} L};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for getting involved!

I'll post a more detailed response below as a separate answer so that I can include some code snippets.

Comment: Just FYI, the link `https://latex.scharrer-online.de/tikz-timing` seems to be broken.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Thanks for the hint. Updated.